# Jest : jest.mock does not work for mocking

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

when unit test jest.mock doesn't work.
that's why when did toBeCalled() test() doesn't call...

i created these func

test.ts

```
export const test = () => {
  return console.log("call test")
}

export const parentTest = () => {
  return test()
}
```

and then i wrote like these code on **tests**/utils/test.ts

```
import { parentTest, test } from "@/test"


jest.mock("@/test", () => ({
  parentTest: jest.requireActual("@/test").parentTest,
  test: jest.fn(),
}))

describe("parentTest", () => {
  it("should call test() within parentTest()", () => {
    parentTest() // Call the parentTest function
    expect(test).toBeCalled()
  })
})
```

and i received this error

```
 FAIL  __tests__/utils/test.ts
  ● parentTest › should call test() within parentTest()

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      18 |     parentTest() // Call the parentTest function
      19 |     
    > 20 |     expect(test).toBeCalled()
         |                  ^
      21 |   })
      22 | })
      23 |

      at Object.toBeCalled (__tests__/utils/test.ts:20:18)
```

i couldn't understand why test() doesn't call